# How to produce a scalable version of a new (arrow) symbol?

Tags: tikz-arrows

NEW VERSION of the question:

Let me *try* to be **very precise** about what I'm looking for, incorporating here what I have written at a comment to the earlier version of my question. 
As in the illustration to be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423241/159160), I want to produce a number of arrows

`->, <-, <->, =>, <=, <=>`

all looking *exactly like*, resp., LaTeX's \rightarrow, \leftarrow, \leftrightarrow, \Rightarrow, \Leftarrow, \Leftrightarrow, and **also** produce, in a standard way, the arrows

`>-, -<, >-<, >=, =<, >=<`

which are not native to LaTeX but should look like the arrows above, except that they invert the directions of the arrow heads.

It is **extremely important** that these new arrows should scale in a natural way, *just like* the native LaTeX arrows, when used in subscripts or superscripts.

(Notice that smooth scaling is fundamental, but only *part* of my problem.)

---

OLD VERSION of the question:

In the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423241/159160) I learned how to produce some new
   arrow symbols that I was in need of. I would now like to make these
   symbols *scalable*, so that they could be used in subscripts or
   superscripts without ad hoc adaptations. Can anyone help?

Comment: You could use the `scalerel` package of Steven B. Segletes: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/scalerel/scalerel.pdf

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this questoin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175443/how-to-use-a-custom-scalable-symbol-in-latex). (Just replace the `\includegraphics` with your arrow.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a custom, scalable, symbol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175443/how-to-use-a-custom-scalable-symbol-in-latex)

Comment: @Sebastiano Many thanks. The examples I find in the documentation of the package and in the related question pointed out by the other users employ \def rather than \NewDocumentCommand. I know it should be "obvious" how to adapt them for the use of scalerel, but so far I have not managed to make it work for the command \imparrow, in my code... Could you be so kind as to give a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer at the cited question...

Also using `scalerel`, but the result seems different than the other answer.

EDITED to express results in `ex` rather than `pt`, so that the answer was not specifically geared to the OP's specification of `\LARGE`.

EDITED to use `\mathrel`.

EDITED to make double arrows same width as single arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\scaled[1]{\scaleto{#1}{\dimexpr1.8\LMex+0.43ex}}

\newcommand{\MyArc}[1][1]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \fill[white]
            (0,0) arc (270:180:3.5*\ArW) -- (0,3.5*\ArW) -- cycle ;
        \draw   (0,0) arc (270:180:3.5*\ArW) ;
        \fill[white]
            (0,0) arc (90:180:3.5*\ArW) -- (0,-3.5*\ArW) -- cycle ;
        \draw (0,0) arc (90:180:3.5*\ArW) ;
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\MyArcRv}[1][1]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \fill[white] (0,3.5*\ArW) arc (0:-90:3.5*\ArW)
            arc (90:0:3.5*\ArW) -- cycle ;
        \draw (0,3.5*\ArW) arc (0:-90:3.5*\ArW)
            arc (90:0:3.5*\ArW) ;
    \end{scope}
}

\tikzset{%
    Arrow width/.store in=\ArW,
    Arrow width=.18ex,
    pics/.cd,
    arc east/.style={code = {\MyArc[xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}},
    arc west/.style={code = {\MyArc[rotate=180,xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}},
    arc rv east/.style={code = {\MyArcRv[xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}},
    arc rv west/.style={code = {\MyArcRv[rotate=180,xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\imparrow}{
    D<>{} % above
    O{1em} %length
    m % pattern
    D<>{} % below
    }{\mathrel{\scaled{%
    \def\Law{}
    \def\Raw{}
    \def\Style{}
    \def\Dlen{#2}
    \IfBeginWith{#3}{<}{\def\Law{pic{arc west}}}{}
    \IfBeginWith{#3}{>}{\def\Law{pic{arc rv west}}}{}
    \IfEndWith{#3}{>}{\def\Raw{pic{arc east}}}{}
    \IfEndWith{#3}{<}{\def\Raw{pic{arc rv east}}}{}
    \IfSubStr[1]{#3}{=}{\def\Style{double}\def\Dlen{.85em}}{}
    \tikz [baseline=-.5ex,line width=.11ex, double distance=.33ex]
        \draw[\Style] (0,0) \Law
            -- node[below=-2pt] {#1} node[above=-2pt] {#4}
            (\Dlen,0) \Raw;}}}
\begin{document}
%\LARGE 
\newcommand\stencil[1]{%
  $\alpha #1 \beta  /
  \scriptstyle \alpha #1 \beta /
  \scriptscriptstyle \alpha #1 \beta$\par
}
\stencil{\to}
\stencil{\Leftrightarrow}
\smallskip
versus
\smallskip

\renewcommand\stencil[1]{%
  $\alpha \imparrow{#1} \beta  /
  \scriptstyle \alpha \imparrow{#1} \beta /
  \scriptscriptstyle \alpha \imparrow{#1} \beta$\par
}
\stencil{->}
\stencil{<->}
\stencil{<-}
\stencil{>-}
\stencil{-<}
\stencil{>-<}
\stencil{=>}
\stencil{<=>}
\stencil{<=}
\stencil{>=}
\stencil{=<}
\stencil{>=<}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, also for you +1. But the bounty when it will gives :-)?

Comment: @Sebastiano If only I understood `tikz`, I could make the double bars farther apart...

Comment: This looks pretty good, thanks! I have not confirmed the bounty, however, for the code does not precisely fulfill the specification...

Comment: @JMarcos Yes, I don't know `tikz` and so I (so far) have not figured out how to make the double arrows more separated in their lines.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think _that_ you can do by writing something like `double distance=1.4pt`, together with `baseline` and `line width`. But I still have the trouble of smoothly scaling the symbols!

Comment: @JMarcos Thanks.  I stumbled through it, and it seems to be improved.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks! Your package `scalerel` is wonderfully useful. I wish I could see this code compile so as to at least look similar to your pic. Do you think there is any explanation for the fact that eight out of twelve symbols are actually getting _larger_ under `scriptstyle`, when I compile in any of my computers, than under normalsize?

Comment: @JMarcos It would appear that I tailored the result to `\LARGE`, which you were in.  That comes from specifying things in `pt` rather than `em` and `ex`.  I will see if I can revise.

Comment: @JMarcos Please try again.  Also, make sure you are using `scalerel 2016/12/29 v1.8`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks again. It was indeed essential to update the 2015 version of `scalerel` that I had installed in my machine.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse,xstring,scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newcommand{\MyArc}[1][1]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \fill[white]
            (0,0) arc (270:180:4*\ArW) -- (0,4*\ArW) -- cycle ;
        \draw   (0,0) arc (270:180:4*\ArW) ;
        \fill[white]
            (0,0) arc (90:180:4*\ArW) -- (0,-4*\ArW) -- cycle ;
        \draw (0,0) arc (90:180:4*\ArW) ;
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\MyArcRv}[1][1]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \fill[white] (0,4*\ArW) arc (0:-90:4*\ArW)
            arc (90:0:4*\ArW) -- cycle ;
        \draw (0,4*\ArW) arc (0:-90:4*\ArW)
            arc (90:0:4*\ArW) ;
    \end{scope}
}


\tikzset{%
    Arrow width/.store in=\ArW,
    Arrow width=.7pt,
    pics/.cd,
    arc east/.style={code = {\MyArc[xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}},
    arc west/.style={code = {\MyArc[rotate=180,xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}},
    arc rv east/.style={code = {\MyArcRv[xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}},
    arc rv west/.style={code = {\MyArcRv[rotate=180,xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]}}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\imparrow}{
    D<>{} % above
    O{1.4em} %length
    m % pattern
    D<>{} % below
    }{%
    \def\Law{}
    \def\Raw{}
    \def\Style{}
    \IfBeginWith{#3}{<}{\def\Law{pic{arc west}}}{}
    \IfBeginWith{#3}{>}{\def\Law{pic{arc rv west}}}{}
    \IfEndWith{#3}{>}{\def\Raw{pic{arc east}}}{}
    \IfEndWith{#3}{<}{\def\Raw{pic{arc rv east}}}{}
    \IfSubStr[1]{#3}{=}{\def\Style{double}}{}
    \scalerel*{
    \tikz [baseline=-.5ex,line width=.4pt]
        \draw[\Style] (-3pt,0) (0,0) \Law
            -- node[below=-2pt] {#1} node[above=-2pt] {#4}
            (#2,0) \Raw
            ++(3pt,0);}{$\beta$}
     }
\begin{document}


$\alpha\to\beta$ / $\alpha\Leftrightarrow\beta$\bigskip

$\alpha \imparrow{->} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{<->} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{<-} \beta$

\Large 

$\alpha \imparrow{>-} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{-<} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{>-<} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{=>} \beta$

\footnotesize

$\alpha \imparrow{<=>} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{<=} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{>=} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{=<} \beta$

$\alpha \imparrow{>=<} \beta$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me where to put the \scalerel in the code you sent me earlier! By the way, it seems you should have used {\beta} rather than {$\beta$} as the second argument of \scalerel?

Comment: Both works, but if are sure to use it always in math mode, you can use \beta, if not you also can use \ensuremath as third way.

Comment: By the way, are these symbols supposed to fully scale automatically when used in a subscript or superscript? The one thing that I find a bit undesirable about the new symbols, which are otherwise great, is that the arcs of the arrows seem to become disproportional to the whole thing when the arrow is scaled... That is a different behavior from the one I observe in \to when used in a subscript.

Comment: Please mix both methods (your and mine) upon your taste. I can't figure what proportions are suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying... My initial idea was that (your) \imparrow{->} should like exactly like LaTeX's standard \to, that \imparrow{=>} should like exactly like LaTeX's \Rightarrow, and similarly for \imparrow{<->} versus \leftrightarrow, and for \imparrow{<=>} versus \Leftrightarrow. The other symbols would all be produced then by simply moving the arcs to the right positions. Surely I would be happy if the new symbols would scale smoothly in an analogous way to their LaTeX standard counterparts.

Comment: @Tarass and **J Marcos** With so much sincerity I use very little `scarerel` package and I'm not an expert like many users here. The Tarass's answer is impeccably. I upvote now you.